# Dell PowerEdge R740 stuck in boot loop with UEFI0116 error

Tags: dell-poweredge, drivers, hba

LOOOOONG story short, I killed my HBA. I have a spare so I popped it in, and now I'm getting the following screen when I boot:[image]

I hit a key and go into the config, then click on the LSI Driver listed and then I get this screen:[image]

I can't do anything with the keyboard here. The only thing I CAN do is to hit Default, so I do, then save changes and it tells me it's ok now.[image]

I exit out and it takes me back to this screen.[image]

I can't get past it. If I turn it off and back on, it goes to the first screen. I'm stuck in a loop and have no idea what to do!  I tried moving slots and risers, but I keep getting the same thing.

[image]

Additional Details/Steps:
I disconnected the shelf and removed all the drives from the front.

When I booted up, I couldn't get into the Lifecycle manger, it would hit me with that error before it brough it up. I couldn't get into the boot menu either.

I removed the HBA and rebooted and THEN I could get into the lifecycle manager.  I went to "Retire or Repurpose" then it had checkboxes of stuff to delete. I selected the Lifecycle ones to kill/clear those configs/logs. The hardware options were not available at all, and my keyboard still does not work. Maybe it's an issue with the keyboard and the UEFI?

It reset and shut down. I popped all the dives back in and it rebooted and did a new config and shut down again. When I rebooted it booted into TrueNAS. Everything looked good there except for the missing pool from the drive shelf that isn't attached.

I shut it down and installed the HBA and I got the damn error again! UGH!!

Comment: It doesn't see any of your disks attached. Do they even blink when you powering the system on? Do as it says: power off the server, disassemble it, check cabling, assemble back and enter the configuration utility. Probably you need to use [Tab] key on that screen to change focus to on-screen elements other than "Default", or even use mouse for that.

Comment: I have 16 SSDs in the front.  I can see a light cycle through them all 3 times.  The HBA is connected to the disk shelf above it.  The green lights all briefly blinked once during boot.  I don't think they really do much, there are no activity lights.  I have tried EVERY button on the keyboard and nothing works in that Driver Health Utility.  I've read posts where hitting C allows you to clear out the existing drive config, but I can't get there.

Comment: The driver utility says LSI MegaRAID SAS 9286CV.  It was supposed to be in IT mode to be used as a HBA. I am wondering if it isn't, and has the previous setup saved in it or something.

Comment: WIth IT firmware it's in the HBA mode, you must have had direct access to all the drives directly from the OS. Was it like that before it broke, or were there some RAID arrays? If there were any, that was not an IT firmware. If it was IT, you can just replace this HBA with literally any other HBA and live happily. I also had an experience with installed LSI-branded controller and reconnected drives from PERC to it; that was not in IT mode, so there were arrays, and it recognized arrays and system started as if nothing changed.

Comment: why not open a support case on the vendor? Dell has a significant great service and solutions. but hopefully you bought it? ;)